# rust zip function that copies values rather than referencing them

Tags: rust

I would like to zip two vectors together, but what I get when calling the zip function is (&i32, &i32). I would like to get (i32, i32) - copy values from both vectors into a new vector.

```
let v1 = vec![1,2,3];
let v1 = vec![4,5,6];

// what I want
let zipped : Vec<(i32, i32)> = v1.iter().zip(v2.iter()).collect();

// what I actually get
let zipped : Vec<(&i32, &i32)> = v1.iter().zip(v2.iter()).collect();
```

Is it possible to force the zip function to copy the values?

Comment: It's not `zip` that creates the references, it's `v.iter()`. Use `v.into_iter()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zip()` doesn't influence the values you're iterating over, it simply creates an iterator over tuples of the first and second iterator's values.

If you want to get owned values, you can use `into_iter()` on the `Vec`s. This will consume the vectors, so you can't use them anymore after the call. If you need to keep those vectors around, there's a `copied()` method that can be called on iterators over types that implement `Copy`, which is the case for `i32`. So you can get the same result while keeping the `Vec`s around by `v1.iter().copied().zip(v2.iter().copied()).collect()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned):

```rust
let zipped : Vec<(i32, i32)> = v1.iter().cloned().zip(v2.iter().cloned()).collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df30e394792bd1e0541ed377ef92c7de)